# React Native IOS After Build

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment, itunes

I followed all [the steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) to create the iOS version of the application. Finally, I build over xcode and see that the process is successful.
Now this project I build will be sent to apple store. None of the places I read says what to do after build. I do not know how it works because I'm strangers to the IOS platform. If someone who has previously installed the app helps, please be grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To Upload your app to Appstore, you need to have developer certificate and provisioning profile, uploading to itunesconnect is easy to work with xcode. select ***Generic iOS device***  form the simulator selection dropdown list and then click on product menu ***archive***, it will archive the project and an ipa file will be generated then the generated ipa file can be upload to appstore. you need to properly setup provisioning profile for the app in itunes connect. From itunesConnect you can submit the app to appstore for reviewing your app and later you can decide app to be automatically submited to app store or manual submission. For more info [refer here](https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/).

Comment: So does `archive` generate the `.ipa` file using the build created by `react-native run-ios` or does `archive` function independently?